# zsh: command not found even though it is in the path

Tags: zsh

I have an executable in the PATH, which I can execute by cd-ing into the directory that contains it. But I can't execute it outside of that directory. I am on a mac. The executable is called rosetta-cli. It is located at `~/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli`.

I am not very familiar with zsh and bash, I just know the bare minimum to get by :)

```
septerr@septerr ~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/Users/septerr/.rbenv/bin:/Users/septerr/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/Users/septerr/.rbenv/bin:/Users/septerr/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/septerr/go/bin:/Users/septerr/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli:/Users/septerr/go/bin:/Users/septerr/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli

septerr@septerr ~ % rosetta-cli
zsh: command not found: rosetta-cli

septerr@septerr ~ % rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli
CLI for the Rosetta API

Usage:
  rosetta-cli [command]

Available Commands:
  check:construction           Check the correctness of a Rosetta Construction API Implementation
  check:data                   Check the correctness of a Rosetta Data API Implementation
```

My .zshrc:

```
eval "$($(go env GOPATH)/bin/assume-role -init)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
export GO111MODULE=on
export GOPROXY=https://gomodules.cbhq.net/
export GONOSUMDB=github.cbhq.net  # For Go 1.13 and laterexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export MONOREPO_PATH="/Users/septerr/src/sgupta/repo" && source $MONOREPO_PATH/scripts/rc/rc.sh

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli
```

My .bash_profile:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export GO111MODULE=on
export GOPROXY=https://gomodules.cbhq.net/
export GONOSUMDB=github.cbhq.net  # For Go 1.13 and laterexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export MONOREPO_PATH="/Users/septerr/src/sgupta/repo" && source $MONOREPO_PATH/scripts/rc/rc.sh
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli
```

My .bashrc:

```
eval "$($(go env GOPATH)/bin/assume-role -init)"
export MONOREPO_PATH="/Users/septerr/src/sgupta/repo" && source $MONOREPO_PATH/scripts/rc/rc.sh
```

Questions -

1. Why is rosetta-cli command not available from any directory?
2. Why some of the paths in $PATH are repeated?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. The PATH repetition is a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeset -Ug path` to remove duplicate items from your `PATH` in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

You can trust your shell, that if it says *command not found*, the executable is not in the PATH, respectively it is not an executable.

You showed the PATH and the name of the command, but you did not tell us which directory this executable is supposed to be in. Making an educated guess, I would say that `/Users/septerr/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli` should be the place for the executable (but this is something you need to know better than I do). If you agree so far, just do a

```
ls /Users/septerr/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli/rosetta-cli
```

If `rosetta-cli` is really an executable in this directory, `ls` should show it, **and the x-bit should be turned on**.